# Bash Script Command Issue

Tags: bash, scripting, cygwin

I when I type the following command into cygwin:

```
bin/nutch index crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segment/*
```

then the binary works fine.  When I place the exact same line into my bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash/
bin/nutch index crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segment/*
```

I get an error saying some files don't exist.  This may be specific to Nutch which is the program I'm running, but I think it has more to do with how I'm calling the command in the script.  Any ideas about what's wrong and how to fix this? (yes I'm using tab completion)

EDIT:

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/bin/nutch index crawl/indexes crawl/crawldb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*
```

I run the command:

```
$ pwd
/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2
$ ./nutch.sh
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Indexer: starting at 2010-11-29 15:15:44
Indexer: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/
/crawl_fetch
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/
/crawl_parse
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/
/parse_data
Input path does not exist: file:/C:/cygwin/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/
/parse_text
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.SequenceFileInputFormat.listStatus(SequenceFileInputFormat.java:44)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:201)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeOldSplits(JobClient.java:810)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:781)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:730)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1249)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.index(Indexer.java:76)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.run(Indexer.java:97)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
    at org.apache.nutch.indexer.Indexer.main(Indexer.java:106)
```

Regards,
~DS

Comment: make sure `/bin/bash` is the correct path. Also, `bin/nutch` is a relative path.

Comment: I have tested other commands in the script using this bin/nutch directory and they have worked fine.  I take this to mean that these are all okay.  What is the difference between running a command in a script and on the command line?  Is there any way to bridge the gap between the 2 completely?

Comment: Can you post the script and o/p you are seeing ?

Comment: Okay, I think the issue is that the command I'm running generates temporary directories.  And when I call the command in a script it assumes they already exist.  Is this true?

Comment: I haven't solved this yet.  Still getting the error.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your problem has something to do with mixing Windows paths with Cygwin paths. Neither Windows nor Cygwin know what to do with `file:/C:/cygwin/home/Dan/apache-nutch-1.2/`. Change the slashes to backslashes to make Windows happy or remove the "C:/cygwin" to make Cygwin happy. I'm not sure what to do about the "file:/". Also see `man cygpath` to see if you find any hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. You've got a trailing slash after "bash" in the shebang at the start of the script -- remove it, it should just read `#!/bin/bash`. Also double check there is a `bash` in `/bin`.
2. The script will try and execute nutch from the `bin` directory in your currect folder. So if you're in `$HOME`, and assuming you've got a path `$HOME/bin/nutch`, then you'll be okay. But then if you change to `/tmp`, then it'll fail as there's no such path as `/tmp/bin/nutch`. You're better off giving the full *absolute* path name to nutch in the first place.

Comment: Actually, I'm running the script from home/.../apache-nutch-1.2/ which contains "/bin/nutch".  I fixed the #!/bin/bash.  Perhaps the fact that I'm calling the script from a relative address is causing the issue?  How would I fix that?